# Fractional classes with Tailwind CSS inside a HAML file

Tags: ruby, haml, tailwind-css

I am trying to use the `w-2/3` class from Tailwind CSS with HAML in a Rails `.html.haml` file. The forward slash is causing Rails (or HAML) to throw an exception and I don't know how to format it so it's accepted.

Is there a way to use the `w-2/3` etc classes or will I have to go back to using `.html.erb`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to explicitly add the class, something like

```
%div{:class => "w-2/3"}
```

Note you can combine this with the shorthand syntax for classes if you want, e.g.

```
.foo{:class => "w-2/3"}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your reply. I'll give it a go when I'm back near my development machine and then accept your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The class names used in Tailwind can be overwritten. This might help if you tend to use these classes frequently and don't want to write the extended version (`%div{class: 'w-1/2'}` or `%div(class="w-1/2")`.

To overwrite the width classes to use `_` instead of `/`, use the following configuration in your `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    width: (theme) => ({
      auto: 'auto',
      ...theme('spacing'),
      '1_2': '50%',
      '1_3': '33.333333%',
      '2_3': '66.666667%',
      '1_4': '25%',
      '2_4': '50%',
      '3_4': '75%',
      '1_5': '20%',
      '2_5': '40%',
      '3_5': '60%',
      '4_5': '80%',
      '1_6': '16.666667%',
      '2_6': '33.333333%',
      '3_6': '50%',
      '4_6': '66.666667%',
      '5_6': '83.333333%',
      '1_12': '8.333333%',
      '2_12': '16.666667%',
      '3_12': '25%',
      '4_12': '33.333333%',
      '5_12': '41.666667%',
      '6_12': '50%',
      '7_12': '58.333333%',
      '8_12': '66.666667%',
      '9_12': '75%',
      '10_12': '83.333333%',
      '11_12': '91.666667%',
      full: '100%',
      screen: '100vw',
    }),
  }
}
```

Obviously, this duplicates information from Tailwind and might make framework upgrades more cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is also incredibly helpful!